# Sharepoint - user can log in only from one computer

Tags: claims-based-auth

We are using claims based authentication and observing strange behavior - one user can log in only from one browser (computer). The second the same user logs in on second browser (computer) his session dies on the first one. Did anyone observe similar behavior? How to fix it and let same user log in from multiple computers?

Comment: You'll get a better response if you post this on [SharePoint.SE]

Answer (score 1):

Try few more options

1. Add the site to trusted site zone for Internet Explorer
2. Try using other browsers
3. Do you have customization to your site ? Try an OOTB site collection

Sandeep